# Cannot call an sql connection from php

Tags: php, sql, ubuntu

(Running ubuntu server 12.04)

This line in particular is giving me issues in php:

```
$con = mysql_connect("localhost:3306","root","root");
```

From turning on error reporting, I only got this returned (as it was killed at that line and nothing afterwards would print):

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysql_connect() in /var/www/sql/login.php on line 7
```

I'm not sure where to go from there, as it is just killed at the line I provided. I have used just "localhost" as well, and I have successfully logged in from the command line. Could this be a php permissions issue, or something like configuration? If so, where would that be?

Comment: You don't have MySQL, but you might have MySQLi. Try `mysqli_connect()` instead...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this happen because you don't have the mysql extension loaded on your php environment.

To fix this, in your ubuntu open the shell and type this:

```
sudo apt-get install php5-mysql libapache2-mod-auth-mysql
```

After that, just restart apache with the next command:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Your version of PHP was compiled without MySQL support. You need to recompile it, following the [setup instructions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysql.installation.php) for including MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

The `php_mysql` library is not installed on your server. Try to take a look at the output of `phpinfo()` if it is really missing.